# iOS Safari Crashes loading iframe

Tags: ios, iframe, safari, crash

This page crashes (well, shuts down Safari) when loaded into Safari on iOS 7.1.x. Note that it does use an iframe. The crash only happens with some pages (like this one), I think due to the page's size (this one is relatively large). Desktop browsers display the page fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language">
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <iframe src="http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lance_Armstrong"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Fixes?